# Relative file paths in Python packages

Tags: python, reference, package, relative-path

How do I reference a file relatively to a package's directory?

My directory structure is:

```
    /foo
     package1/
      resources/
      __init__.py
     package2/
      resources/
      __init__.py
     script.py
```

`script.py` imports packages `package1` and `package2`. Although the packages can be imported by any other script on the system. How should I reference resources inside, say, `package1` to ensure it would work in case `os.path.curdir` is arbitrary?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to reference files from the `foo/package1/resources` folder you would want to use the `__file__` variable of the module. Inside `foo/package1/__init__.py`:

```
from os import path
resources_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'resources')
```

Comment: As noted by another answer, this won't work if your application is packaged in a zip file.

Answer (score 14):

A simple/safe way to do this is using the `resource_filename` method from [pkg_resources](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) (which is distributed with [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)) like so:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
filepath = resource_filename('package1', 'resources/thefile')
```

Or, if you're implementing this inside `package1/___init___.py`:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
filepath = resource_filename(__name__, 'resources/thefile')
```

This gives you a clean solution that is also (if I'm not mistaken) zip safe.

Answer (score 4):

You can be zip-safe and at the same time use a nice convenient API if you use [twisted.python.modules](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.python.modules.html).

For example, if I have a `data.txt` with some text in it and and this `sample.py` in one directory:

```
from twisted.python.modules import getModule
moduleDirectory = getModule(__name__).filePath.parent()
print repr(moduleDirectory.child("data.txt").open().read())
```

then importing `sample` will do this:

```
>>> import sample
'Hello, data!\n'
>>>
```

If your module is in a regular directory, `getModule(__name__).filePath` will be a [FilePath](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.python.filepath.FilePath.html); if it's in a zip file, it will be a [ZipPath](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.python.zippath.ZipPath.html), which supports most, but not all, of the same APIs.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad idea, because, if your package was installed as zipped egg, then resources can be unavailable.

If you use setuptool, don't forget to add zip_safe=False to the setup.py config.

Comment: This is true, but it should really have been in a comment rather than an answer, since it doesn't answer the question.