# Unable to import text file with Python module

Tags: python, import, module

I'm writing a simple Python module (called `event_classifier`) for a project that I'm currently working on and am having the following issue. There is a text file (`categories.txt`) that contains several strings that I need to read using various functions in the module. However, when I import the classes from the module using the following command

```
from event_classifier import *
```

I get an error, because the functions open `categories.txt` using the relative path to the file within the `event_classifier` directory. Thus, when I import the module, the file is not imported with it, so it no longer exists there.

By the way, my `__init__.py` file inside `event_classifier` just has the following

```
from Event import *
from alg import *
```

(it just imports all of the classes and functions from the other files in the module).

*Has anyone had this problem before and was able to come up with a working solution?*

Comment: Are you actually trying to _import_ that text file, or just `open` it and read text from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative file paths in Python packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011337/relative-file-paths-in-python-packages)

Comment: Are you sure it is opening the file relative to the module's directory?  Can we see the error that is being produced please?  (full traceback)

Answer (score 0):

A relative path is, by default, relative to *the current working directory*.

If you're trying to open a file at a fixed location *relative to your module* instead, you have to do that explicitly.

For example:

```
import os

module_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
textfile_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'categories.txt')
with open(textfile_path) as f:
    # etc.
```

However, this usually isn't the best solution. It's better to design a complex package like this to be installed, rather than used directly in the source tree, and use `setuptools` features to put data files in a (platform-appropriate) standard location at install time, and then access them from that location at runtime using the [`pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) API.